# Can you use componentDidMount() on a React class that doesn't extend Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created my React class like such:

```
const MyMap = () => {
    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }

    return {
        ...
    }
}
```

I realized that componentDidMount() is not being recognized and is not working. Is this because I didn't extend React.Component? Also, is there an alternative I can use for the React class I created?

Answer (score 4):

you could use `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  // write your logic here   
}, []);
```

as they mention [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook)

> The Effect Hook, `useEffect`, adds the ability to perform side effects from a function component. It serves the same purpose as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` in React classes